# Does mAnasika puja or mAnasika anushtanam or mAnasika UpAsana have any basis in ItihAsAs or Smritis or Upanishads or Vedas?

Tags: puja, gayatri-mantra, sandhyavandanam

mAnasika pUja is lauded & bheema is given as an example. If so, what stops one who is lying down in sleep at 4am everyday, instead of getting up, just continue lying down and then do in his mind mAnasika  sandhyAvandanam and be done with it?

Comment: The pharma will also be like that maybe will get golden chest I  dream

Comment: if you want mAnasika phalan, sure :). Instead of getting real wealth/fame/whatever as reward, you can get a dream of wealth/fame/whatever as reward for manasika tapas

Comment: @ram - that is not what is in vouge though. The legend narrated about mAnasika puja is bheema apparently did it whereas Arjuna didn't, and consequently Sri Krishna always came to Bheema's aid unasked, whereas he only came to Arjuna's & yudhistra's aid only when asked. I am not saying that is right nor not, merely what is currently preached by preachers and believed by the masses.

Comment: @VijaySharma, if that were the case then there is no point in shastras telling us to do real/normal puja. manasika is for contingencies. since any action first has to stem from thought, then words, then action, it is assumed that those who act do so when the inner devotion overflows. but many people do puja without the inner-devotion/sanctity, and that's where Bhima excelled. In other words, when comparing thought alone to action alone, 'thought alone' is better, but thought + action is the best.

Comment: Manasa Puja is widely found in Tantras. In fact, before an external Puja, Manasa Puja is ought to be done. But In the Smritis, I have never found anything like "Manasik Sandhyavandanam" @VijaySharma

Comment: @ram - can you provide some scriptural reference to what you said here, and make it an answer to this questions for upvote rather than a comment.

Comment: mAnasika sandhyAvandanam might have been practiced by advanced practitioners.  Further, it might be applicable in the case of people, who are temporarily down with diseases or who are in advanced age and can't do physically.  Beginner should not resort to such practices as they may result in sleep instead of practice:-)

Comment: @srimannarayana k v - I am not a beginner btw, I have been a gayatri upasaka for 22 yrs now (started regular sandhyavandana gayatri upasana the day of my upanayan ceremony in Feb of 1998). Also see my answer below; if you can translate that video it would be very helpful for all visitors.

Comment: @VijaySharma: Sorry you have understood in a different way.  Advanced practitioners  doesn't indicate the number of years one has been engaged in sandhyavandana. It indicates advancement in terms of achievement, , what is meant for.  For example though Sri Ramana Maharishi was at the age of 16 years and Sri Kaavya kantha Ganapati sastry was much elder to him in age, the latter became disciple of the former

Comment: @VijaySharma: I have posted my answer.  Good question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have listened [to the answer in the Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SLgesbncPus) by Sri Mylavarapu Srinivasa Rao, a renowned ***pravachan karta***, in Telugu speaking areas.

Yes, he did explain about ***mAnasika sandhyAvandanam***.

He explained the following issues:

- In the olden days, people used to do ***sandhyAvandanam***, without the paraphernalia, viz., photo of Gayatri mata, flowers, etc, while they are moving.
- They used to do ***Achamanam*** and after keeping the Gayatri mata figure in mind, start doing Gayatri mantra japa.
- we can do all pre-requisites, viz., sankalpa, Achamanam, etc, mentally, and start doing japa.
- ***mAnasika sandhyAvandanam*** is far better than ***physical sandhyavandanam***, which requires the paraphernalia

---

The above ***mAnasika sandhyAvandanam*** has scriptual reference also.

Sage Viswamitra wakes up Sri Rama and Lakshmana during twilight period, and advises them to attend ***sandhyavandam***.

> कौसल्या सुप्रजा राम पूर्वा संध्या प्रवर्तते | उत्तिष्ठ नरशार्दूल
> कर्तव्यं दैवमाह्निकम् || १-२३-२
>
> "Fortunate is Kausalya to beget you as her son Rama... get up oh,
> tigerly-man, eastern aurora is emerging, daytime tasks towards gods
> are to be performed."

They are not carrying any paraphernalia, viz., photo of Gayatri mata, flowers, etc, as  they were moving.

Sri Rama performed sandhyavanam mentally.

> तस्यर्षेः परमोदारं वचः श्रुत्वा नरोत्तमौ | स्नात्वा कृतोदकौ वीरौ
> जेपतुः परमं जपम् || १-२३-३
>
> On hearing the benign words of the sage those valorous and best ones
> among men got up, bathed, and on offering water oblation they
> meditated upon the supreme hymn, namely Gayatri.

---

***A word of caution:***

It is not advisable to do mAnasika sandhyAvandanam by the beginners, not in literal sense but in terms of advancement in doing japa, as it may not be done properly.

Answer (score 0):

So I found this video in which a Telugu *pravachan karta* is answering a question and telling viewers HOW to do mAnasika sandhyAvandan:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SLgesbncPus

I obtained a translation of the gist of what he is saying in this video - that yes, you can do mAnasika sandhyAvandan (he doesn't mention doing it lying down in sleep obviously). But it looks like it can be done. And this gentleman is a revered veda educated brahmin from Telugu community.

If anyone here speaks Telugu, then I request them to fully translate into english what he is saying and post it here for benefit of us all in Stack Exchange community.